# directorysearcher pagesize confusion

Tags: c#, active-directory, .net-4.5

I have been looking over Microsoft's documentation and the posts here on getting search results from DirectorySearcher. I am writing code not sure the best performing way to get a lot of results from AD (right now testing with 4K results, but should scale for more).

**Question 1:** What is the best method?

Here are my efforts so far.

**Run 1 description** 
I did not set the PageSize which returns 2000 (this seems to be the default on the AD server - not 1000 that I read from posts/documentation). I do not know how to get the remainder of the results. I tried making calls to `Dispose()` and then `FindAll()` multiple times. That did not work (gave me same results over and over).

**Question 2:** How do I get **all** the results this way?

Run 1:

```
//ds.PageSize - not setting this property
log.Debug("PageSize=" + ds.PageSize);
log.Debug("SizeLimit=" + ds.SizeLimit);
results = ds.FindAll();
log.Debug("AD count: " + results.Count);
```

Run 1 Log

```
PageSize=0
SizeLimit=0
AD Count: 2000
```

**Run 2 description** 
I did the PageSize to higher than my results (though I really do not want to do this for performance fears). I got all the results as expected.

Run 2:

```
ds.PageSize = 5000;
log.Debug("PageSize=" + ds.PageSize);
log.Debug("SizeLimit=" + ds.SizeLimit);
results = ds.FindAll();
log.Debug("AD count: " + results.Count);
```

Run 2 Log

```
PageSize=5000
SizeLimit=0
AD Count: 4066
```

**Run 3 description** 
I set the PageSize to lower than my results so not to impact performance thinking setting this to would then maybe allow the 'pagination' of results by calling `Dispose()` and `FindAll()`. Totally got unexpected results!

Run 3:

```
ds.PageSize = 2000;
log.Debug("PageSize=" + ds.PageSize);
log.Debug("SizeLimit=" + ds.SizeLimit);
results = ds.FindAll();
log.Debug("AD count: " + results.Count);
```

Run 3 Log:

```
PageSize=2000
SizeLimit=0
AD Count: 4066
```

**Question 3:** This makes no sense to me. Please point me to right direction. I thought subsequent calls to `Dispose()` and `FindAll()` would work here. But I got all the results on first go.

Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

The value may have been changed in your environment - it is 1000 by default. You can set the Page Size to 1000 and the `DirectorySearcher` class will handle paging for you. If you set it smaller, that's fine too. You should wrap the code in a `using` block to make sure resources get disposed.

Comment: I have read about the DirectorySearcher class handling the paging, but am unsure what that means. In Run 1 above, I could not figure out how to get the rest of the search results (which I assume to be 4066, but only got 2000).